# How to ignore a specific Exception INSTANCE for an async method in Visual Studio (break on thrown)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception, async-await

If I set VS to break on thrown exceptions of a given type, and the debugger haltet at some piece of code, I look for a possibility to continue running (F5) and **not** break on each parent stack frame of the **same** exception.

In other words, I want a possibility to ignore the very **instance** of the exception for the rest of its stackframe (assuming it is caught somewhere above).

The only way I found is tedious (and error-prone if such exceptions are thrown often in some situation): Uncheck the "break when this type is thrown" checkbox, continue execution, immediately reactivate the exception in the Exception Settings pane.

---

Edit: clarifying to 1st answer

I forgot to mention (as I was not aware that this is relevant info) that I'm in async methods. I modified your example to async, like this:

```
    public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Alpha();

        }
        catch (Exception e) // don't try this at home kids
        {
            // we should never get here in this example
            throw;
        }
    }


    private static async Task Alpha()
    {
        try
        {
            await Bravo(); //  *** 4 ***
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // debugger won't stop here because we didn't re-throw
        }
    }

    private static async Task Bravo()
    {
        try
        {
            await Tango(); //  *** 2 ***
        }
        catch (Exception)  // don't try this at home kids
        {
            throw;  // *** 3 *** debugger will stop here again because we are re-throwing
        }
    }

    private static async Task Tango()
    {
        var x = 1;
        var y = 0;
        var c = x / y; //  *** 1 ***

    }
}
```

And the debugger stops at all four marked spots in the numbered order. So it does not only stop at rethrows, but also at all awaits inbetween. And for deep call hierarchies, this is disturbing my debug-flow, so to speak.

So to summarize, I'd need a solution for async calls to not re-break at every await between the exception-causing stackframe and the one where the exception is eventually caught.

Possible?

Comment: That's not correct `async` code.  Because you don't `await Alpha()`, the program terminates before the rest of your code completes.  On my machine, the program terminates before `Tango()` even attempts to divide by zero let alone throw an exception.  Besides, you don't even create any `Task`s

Comment: Whoops ignore last, I'm using my home computer now and didn't have break on exception thrown turned on.  Give me a moment.

Comment: Yeah not awaiting Alpha() would be problematic in real application code, in this example it's irrelevant for the problem we're discussing, so please ignore that ;)   but with break on exc. thrown, the problem becomes apparent in the example.

Comment: btw, msdn docs say:  "If you await a task-returning async method that causes an exception, the await operator rethrows the exception." (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx). So basically I'm asking for "how to ignore rethrows in break-on-thrown". :-/

Comment: Yes I was just seeing that now in the debugger.  Very interesting.  Didn't know that, thanks for the link.  Sadly I'm at the limit of my knowledge.  Hopefully Mr Stephen Cleary will be along as he is the guru of all things `async` :)

Comment: I've revised the title a bit and added a new `tag` in the hope one of the async gurus can help :)

Answer (score 0):

---

With the new info that became apparent in the question, this answer may no longer be suitable. :)

---

> If I set VS to break on thrown exceptions of a given type, and the debugger haltet at some piece of code, I look for a possibility to continue running (F5) and not break on each parent stack frame of the same exception....
>
> The only way I found is tedious (and error-prone if such exceptions are thrown often in some situation): Uncheck the "break when this type is thrown" checkbox, continue execution, immediately reactivate the exception in the Exception Settings pane

Without seeing your code I can only assume you are **re-throwing** the same exception.

Consider the following code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Alpha();

        }
        catch (Exception e) // don't try this at home kids
        {
            // we should never get here in this example
            throw;
        }

    }

    private static void Alpha()
    {
        try
        {
            Bravo();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // debugger won't stop here because we didn't re-throw
        }
    }

    private static void Bravo()
    {
        try
        {
            Tango();
        }
        catch (Exception)  // don't try this at home kids
        {
            throw;  // debugger will stop here again because we are re-throwing
        }
    }

    private static void Tango()
    {
        var x = 1;
        var y = 0;
        var c = x / y;
    }
}
```

With the debugger set to break when `System.DivideByZeroException` is thrown, the debugger will:

1. stop first in `Tango` where it is attempts to divide by zero and the first exception is thrown
2. stop again in the `catch()` handler in `Bravo` where the exception is thrown again

But it will not stop in `Alpha` because I silently eat the exception.

The behaviour you are seeing is by design.

Comment: Ah, yes, but please see my edit above. This doesn't work for async methods.

Comment: Cheers for the additional info.  Yes sadly I don't think my answer is much use now.  Very interesting behavior when awaiting and an exception is thrown as you pointed out in the doco.  :)

Comment: This document shared useful information about why Exception was not intercepted in Async: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/.

Comment: Thanks for the link (bookmarked), but in this question here I'm considering caught exceptions (not unhandled ones).

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Thanks, but that's not we're talking about